# OpenVPN Segmentation Fault

Tags: centos, openvpn, segmentation-fault

I have a server running CentOS 5.7 and I'm trying to get OpenVPN 2.2.0 to work. To start off, I had this working for quite a while now, but decided to try and make it highly available by using heartbeat for failover to another server. Now I can't even get it to work at all for some reason.

Whenever I try and start openvpn by running `/etc/init.d/openvpn start` it keeps giving me the error

> /etc/init.d/openvpn: line 148:  5820 Segmentation fault      $openvpn
>   --daemon --writepid $piddir/$bn.pid --config $c --cd $work

That section of the script is:

```
 ...

 # Start every .conf in $work and run .sh if exists
        errors=0
        successes=0
        for c in `/bin/ls *.conf 2>/dev/null`; do
            bn=${c%%.conf}
            if [ -f "$bn.sh" ]; then
                . $bn.sh
            fi
            rm -f $piddir/$bn.pid
            $openvpn --daemon --writepid $piddir/$bn.pid --config $c --cd $work
            if [ $? = 0 ]; then
                successes=1
            else
                errors=1
            fi
        done
...
```

Here are my init scripts:

**/etc/openvpn/bridge-start**

```
#!/bin/bash

. /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1

#################################
# Set up Ethernet bridge on Linux
# Requires: bridge-utils
#################################

# Define Bridge Interface
br="br0"

# Define list of TAP interfaces to be bridged,
# for example tap="tap0 tap1 tap2".
tap="tap0"

# Define physical ethernet interface to be bridged
# with TAP interface(s) above.
eth=$DEVICE
eth_ip=$IPADDR
eth_netmask=$NETMASK
eth_broadcast="10.224.45.159"

for t in $tap; do
    openvpn --mktun --dev $t
done

brctl addbr $br
brctl addif $br $eth

for t in $tap; do
    brctl addif $br $t
done

for t in $tap; do
    ifconfig $t 0.0.0.0 promisc up
done

ifconfig $eth 0.0.0.0 promisc up

ifconfig $br $eth_ip netmask $eth_netmask broadcast $eth_broadcast
```

**/etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf**

```
port        1194
proto       tcp

# Bridge
dev tap0
server-bridge   10.224.45.130 255.255.255.0 10.224.45.140 10.224.45.160

ca      /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert        /etc/openvpn/keys/server.crt
key     /etc/openvpn/keys/server.key
dh      /etc/openvpn/keys/dh1024.pem
keepalive   10 120
status      /var/log/openvpn/status.log
log     /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
verb        0
client-to-client
comp-lzo
user nobody
group users
persist-key
persist-tun
client-cert-not-required
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
plugin /usr/lib64/openvpn/plugin/lib/openvpn-auth-ldap.so "/etc/openvpn/auth/ldap.conf"
```

**/etc/openvpn/auth/ldap.conf**

```
<LDAP>
        # LDAP server URL
        URL             ldap://ldap.****.com

        # Bind DN (If your LDAP server doesn't support anonymous binds)
        BindDN          uid=readonly,ou=Users,dc=****,dc=com

        # Bind Password
        Password        <hidden>

        # Network timeout (in seconds)
        Timeout         15

        # Follow LDAP Referrals (anonymously)
        FollowReferrals yes
</LDAP>

<Authorization>
        # Base DN
        BaseDN          "ou=Users,dc=****,dc=com"

        # User Search Filter
        SearchFilter    "(&(uid=%u))"

        # Require Group Membership
        RequireGroup    false
</Authorization>
```

I have no clue what the reason for the segfault could be. I've searched Google for hours now with no luck finding anything related to my issue.

**UPDATE:**

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux master-srv1 2.6.18-274.7.1.el5xen #1 SMP Thu Oct 20 17:06:34 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of `yum info openvpn`:

```
Installed Packages
Name       : openvpn
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 2.2.0
Release    : 3.el5.rf
Size       : 1.0 M
Repo       : installed
Summary    : Robust and highly flexible VPN daemon
URL        : http://openvpn.net/
License    : GPL
Description: OpenVPN is a robust and highly flexible tunneling application.
           : 
           : OpenVPN supports SSL/TLS security, ethernet bridging, TCP or UDP tunnel
           : transport through proxies or NAT, support for dynamic IP addresses and
           : DHCP, scalability to hundreds or thousands of users, and portability to
           : most major OS platforms.
```

**Output of `strace /etc/init.d/openvpn start`:**
(Couldn't fit entire output, so I've pasted the end of it)

```
...

stat("/etc/sysconfig/network", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=79, ...}) = 0
access("/etc/sysconfig/network", X_OK)  = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
access("/etc/sysconfig/network", R_OK)  = 0
open("/etc/sysconfig/network", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=79, ...}) = 0
read(3, "NETWORKING=yes\nNETWORKING_IPV6=y"..., 79) = 79
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
stat("/usr/sbin/openvpn", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=614892, ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b10685b9000
write(1, "Starting openvpn: ", 18Starting openvpn: )      = 18
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [INT CHLD], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [INT CHLD], NULL, 8) = 0
lseek(255, -7, SEEK_CUR)                = 5545
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x2b1064fe4fe0) = 24440
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x436f40, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, 8) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 24440
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
wait4(-1, 0x7fff46543fe4, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
rt_sigreturn(0xffffffffffffffff)        = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, {0x436f40, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
stat("/etc/openvpn/openvpn-startup", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0740, st_size=143, ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x2b1064fe4fe0) = 24441
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x436f40, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, 8) = 0
wait4(-1, 
Running bridge-start...Done
[{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 24441
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
wait4(-1, 0x7fff46544144, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
rt_sigreturn(0xffffffffffffffff)        = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, {0x436f40, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
stat("/var/run/openvpn", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
stat("/var/lock/subsys/openvpn", 0x7fff46544910) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
open("/var/run/openvpn/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
brk(0x1170c000)                         = 0x1170c000
getdents(3, /* 2 entries */, 32768)     = 48
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
brk(0x11704000)                         = 0x11704000
close(3)                                = 0
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/sbin/rm", 0x7fff46544b50)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/rm", 0x7fff46544b50)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/bin/rm", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=47088, ...}) = 0
access("/bin/rm", X_OK)                 = 0
access("/bin/rm", R_OK)                 = 0
stat("/bin/rm", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=47088, ...}) = 0
access("/bin/rm", X_OK)                 = 0
access("/bin/rm", R_OK)                 = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x2b1064fe4fe0) = 24460
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x436f40, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, 8) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 24460
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
wait4(-1, 0x7fff46544824, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
rt_sigreturn(0xffffffffffffffff)        = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, {0x436f40, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, 8) = 0
stat("/etc", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/openvpn", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
chdir("/etc/openvpn")                   = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x2b1064fe4fe0) = 24461
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x436360, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, {0x436360, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, 8) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "openvpn.conf\n", 128)          = 13
read(3, "", 128)                        = 0
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 24461
wait4(-1, 0x7fff46544e94, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
rt_sigreturn(0)                         = 0
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x436f40, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, {0x436f40, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
stat("openvpn.sh", 0x7fff46544840)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
stat("/bin/rm", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=47088, ...}) = 0
access("/bin/rm", X_OK)                 = 0
access("/bin/rm", R_OK)                 = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [INT CHLD], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [INT CHLD], NULL, 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x2b1064fe4fe0) = 24463
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 24463
wait4(-1, 0x7fff46544684, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
rt_sigreturn(0)                         = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x436f40, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, {0x436f40, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, 8) = 0
write(1, "/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --wri"..., 107/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --writepid /var/run/openvpn/openvpn.pid --config openvpn.conf --cd /etc/openvpn
) = 107
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x2b1064fe4fe0) = 24464
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x436f40, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, 8) = 0
wait4(-1, [{WIFSIGNALED(s) && WTERMSIG(s) == SIGSEGV}], 0, NULL) = 24464
fstat(2, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b10685ba000
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "/etc/init.d/openvpn: line 148: 2"..., 129/etc/init.d/openvpn: line 148: 24464 Segmentation fault      $openvpn --daemon --writepid $piddir/$bn.pid --config $c --cd $work
) = 129
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
wait4(-1, 0x7fff46544b74, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
rt_sigreturn(0xffffffffffffffff)        = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, {0x436f40, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e10302d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
write(1, "\33[60G", 5                                      )                  = 5
write(1, "[", 1[)                        = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
write(1, "\33[0;31m", 7)                = 7
write(1, "FAILED", 6FAILED)                   = 6
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
write(1, "\33[0;39m", 7)                = 7
write(1, "]", 1])                        = 1
)                       = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
stat("/usr/bin/rhgb-client", 0x7fff465449a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
read(255, "exit 0\n", 5552)             = 7
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Comment: Show the output of the 'uname -a' and 'dpkg -p openvpn'  (dpkg should be replaced with rpm --info for for centos)

Comment: I've added the output of 'uname -a' and 'yum info openvpn'.

Comment: And one thing more: show the file /etc/openvpn/auth/ldap.conf (no passwords of course)

Comment: I've added the contents of the ldap.conf file.

Comment: The weird thing is that if I run the command that's apparently throwing the segfault outside of the entire script '/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --writepid /var/run/openvpn/openvpn.pid --config openvpn.conf --cd /etc/openvpn' it doesn't throw an error, but also looks like it's not actually starting the openvpn daemon as it should.

Comment: Actually, scratch that, the segfault does happen when running the openvpn command directly. Although it only throws the segfault when I'm in the /etc/openvpn directory. Running the command outside of that directly doesn't throw any segfault.

Comment: Maybe an strace of the openvpn command?

Comment: Added the strace.

Comment: I had similar situation recently when I tried to authenticate against Active directory with openvpn-auth-ldap. Try to coment out the plugin directive in openvpn.conf and restart openvpn. It can help in isolating problem. Note: I'm using domain/username as BindDN.

Comment: And also, why u are not using openvpn's log? it can help a lot. Put verb 5, and read log after failed restart

Comment: I have looked at the logs. There is nothing in there that points to the reason for the error. The last line of the log is 'Thu Nov  3 09:19:53 2011 us=861383 ENVP[8] = 'remote_port_1=1194''. After that there's nothing.

Comment: Try to use full filename paths. Try '/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --writepid /var/run/openvpn/openvpn.pid --config /etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf' and change ipp.txt into full filename path in your config

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't change anything. You know, it's really confusing since this was all working fine yesterday, with pretty much the same settings. I've only done a few minor tweaks here and there, and since then I've even reverted back to the default config/bridge settings with no luck. I did restart my server yesterday, so I'm wondering if something happened during the restart that is affecting this. I really am just guessing at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boban P. was absolutely correct in his comment about the openvpn-auth-ldap plugin being the cause of the segfault. I ruled it out initially since I commented the plugin line out and tried restarting openvpn and it gave the same error. However, openvpn apparently was still trying to use the plugin, so it was still throwing the segfault. I don't know exactly what the issue with the plugin was, but my best guess is that I installed the incorrect version for my system. I made sure to install the one for CentOS from http://pkgs.org/centos-5-rhel-5/flexbox-x86_64/openvpn-auth-ldap-2.0.3-3.centos5.x86_64.rpm.html and it works flawlessly again.

The credit should go to Boban P. for his suggestion regarding openvpn-auth-ldap being the issue.

Comment: I've came across this issue today. The problem is actually the lack of maintenance of the plugin. It hasn't been updated since 2008. You can resolve the issue by using `GCC 4.6` to compile the plugin (more info here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=641811)

Answer (score 0):

I'd uninstall heartbeat, or at least look at the packages associated with heartbeat.  They do something with network interfaces, if I recall, and may be interfering with tun0.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to implement HA on OpenVPN.  My impression is that the recommended way is to use multiple "server" lines in the client configuration.  This won't be seemless, but OpenVPN isn't going to fail over seemlessly anyway, even with Heartbeat, because the session will need to be reinitialized.

Comment: Yeah, heartbeat does modify the eth1 (LAN) interface to add a virtual IP, but I'm working outside of heartbeat at the moment and just trying to get OpenVPN working again. At this point I'm not even starting heartbeat so it shouldn't be interfering with the interface in any way that would affect OpenVPN. I'm just trying to get OpenVPN to start up again, which at this point it's not due to the segfault being thrown. I've tried reinstalling OpenVPN and it didn't help either.